# SQL / (Django) : efficient database schema for translations

Tags: sql, django, database, database-schema

**Situation**

I trying to set up a database schema to store translations, between different languages. So far it looks like this (simplyfied):

```
class Language(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Phrase(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "language")
        index_together = [
            ["name", "language"]
        ]

class Translation(models.Model):
    phrase1 = models.ForeignKey(Phrase, related_name="translation_as_1")
    phrase2 = models.ForeignKey(Phrase, related_name="translation_as_2")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.phrase1.name + " <=> " + self.phrase2.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("phrase1", "phrase2")
        index_together = [
            ["phrase1", "phrase2"]
        ]
```

This database schema seems logical to me. I store phrases in different languages and then have translations that contain exactly two phrases.

**Problem**

The problem is, that the queries, that result out of this schema, look kind of nasty. For instance:

```
from django.db.models import Q

name = "my phrase"
translations = Translation.objects.filter(Q(phrase1__name=text)|Q(phrase2__name=text))
translated_names = []
for translation in translations:
    name1 = translation.phrase1.name
    name2 = translation.phrase2.name
    if name1 == name:
        translated_names.append(name2)
    else:
        translated_names.append(name1)
```

I always have to include the "OR" relationship, to make sure, that I get all the possible translations, since the phrase could be stored as phrase1 or phrase2. On top of that, I have to filter my result afterwards to get the correct translated_name (for loop).

**Further Explaination**

Before I switched to the described schema, I had the following schema instead (`Phrase` and `Language` are the same as before):

```
class Translation(models.Model):
    phrase = models.ForeignKey(Phrase)
    name = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.phrase.name + " => " + self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("phrase", "name")
        index_together = [
            ["phrase", "name"]
```

This schema let me make queries like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

name = "my phrase"
translations = Translation.objects.filter(phrase__name=text)
translated_names = [t.name for t in translations]
```

This looks much nicer, and is of course faster. But this schema had the disadvantage, that it presents translations only in one direction, so I moved to the other one, which isn't quite what I want as well, because too slow and too complicated queries.

**Question**

So is there a good schema for this kind of problem, that I maybe overlook?

**Remark**

I'm not only interested in Django related answers. A pure SQL schema for this kind of problem would also be interesting for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I have done it in the past. Adapt it for your naming convention.

Suppose that I had a table with a name and other columns in it like this

Table **TR_CLT_clothing_type**

```
clt_id | clt_name | other columns ....
--------------------------------------
1      | T Shirt ...
2      | Pants ...
```

Now if I decided that it needs translations, first I make a languages table

Table **TR_LNG_language**

```
lng_id | lng_name | lng_display
-------------------------------
1      | English  | English (NZ)
2      | German   | Deutsch
```

I also need to store the current language in the database (you will see why soon). It will only have one row

Table **TA_INF_info**

```
inf_current_lng
---------------
1
```

Then I drop the *clt_name* column from my clothing table *TR_CLT_clothing_type*. Instead I make relation table.

Table **TL_CLT_clothing_type**

```
clt_id | lng_id | clt_name
--------------------------
1      | 1      | T Shirt
1      | 2      | (German for T-Shirt)
2      | 1      | Pants
2      | 2      | keuchen (thank you google translate)
```

Now to get the name, you want to make a stored procedure for it. I have not attempted this in ORM.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PS_CLT
    @clt_id int
AS

SELECT lng.clt_name, clt.*
FROM TR_CLT_clothing_type clt
JOIN TL_CLT_clothing_type lng
ON lng.clt_id = clt.clt_id
WHERE clt.clt_id = @clt_id AND
      lng.lng_id in (SELECT inf_current_lng FROM TA_INF_info)
```

This stored proc will return the name in the current language and all other columns for a specified language. To set the language, set the *clt_current_lng* in the *TA_INF_info* table.

*Disclaimer: I don't have anything to check the syntax of what I have typed but it should hopefully be straightforward.*

-- EDIT

There was a concern to be able to do "give me all translations for word X in language Y to language Z"

There is a "not so elegant" way to do this with the schema. You can do something like

```
for each table in database like "TL_%"

    SELECT name
    FROM table
    WHERE id IN (   SELECT id
            FROM table
            WHERE name = @name
            AND   lng_id = german
            )
    AND lng_id = english
```

Now I would imagine that this would require some auto-generated SQL code but I could pull it off.

I have no idea how you would do this in ORM

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your suggested way is pretty much, what I had before and described in the "Further Explaination" section. It had the disadvantage, that I wasn't able to store translations in two ways. In the end, I would like to be able to simply and efficient query translations in the following fashion: "give me all translations for word X in language Y to language Z"